# Tabular: continue to the next line if too long horizontally

Tags: tables

I have written a python program that reads in columns from a spreadsheet and produces a feedback sheet in LaTeX for students like so:

[image]

The issue I have is that the number of columns is variable, and depends on the task I have chosen.

Sometimes, there are too many columns and the latex table produced therefore goes off the edge of the page:

[image]

Ideally, I would like latex to recognise that the table has exceeded the edge of the page and just continue it beneath.

Is there any way of doing this? Otherwise, I will need to write some code that will have to chop it up before hand, which is not ideal.

EDIT: the width of the table is unknown before hand: it depends on the number of questions and the description of the questions, hence a dynamic continuation automatically determined by LaTeX is better.

Comment: You know beforehand how many columns you need? So the Python script can produce any LaTeX code? Is uniform length ok for you? Are the tables of the form 3 rows everytime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use one but many tabulars. Add \hspace{0pt} between the tabulars to get a break point, and use \raggedright:

```
\documentclass{article}
\textwidth=10cm
\begin{document}
\raggedright
\begin{tabular}{l}
\hline
Q1\\
Beta Decay Equation\\
\hline
yes\\\hline
\end{tabular}\hspace{0pt}%
\begin{tabular}{l}
\hline
Q1\\
Beta Decay Equation\\
\hline
yes\\\hline
\end{tabular}\hspace{0pt}%
\begin{tabular}{l}
\hline
Q1\\
Beta Decay Equation\\
\hline
yes\\\hline
\end{tabular}\hspace{0pt}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks genius! Let me try this.

Answer (score 0):

If the form is always with 3 rows, you could as well change to vertical and use `longtable`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{l|lc}
    Q1 & Beta Decay Equations & \checkmark\\
    Q2 & Alpha Decay Equations & \checkmark\\
    Q3 & Changes to the Nucleus & \checkmark
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```