# Split Wide Table over Multiple Rows

Tags: tables, multirow, split

I have been looking around and found a lot of ways to split a tall table over multiple pages but no ways to split a wide one over multiple rows.

Basically, I have this:

```
Some paragraph of a certain width which is narrower than the table.
The table is even wider than the page, by a lot.

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Label  | A | B | C | A | B | C | A | B | C | A | B | C | A | B | C | A | B | C | A | B | C | A | B | C | A | B | C | A | B | C | A | B | C |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Values | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But i want this:

```
Some paragraph of a certain width which is narrower than the table.
The table is even wider than the page, by a lot. This table splits 
itself over multiple rows however as to not expand into the margins
sort of like the \split environment for equations.

--------------------------------------------------------------
| Label  | A | B | C | A | B | C | A | B | C | A | B | C | A 
-------------------------------------------------------------- ...
| Values | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 
--------------------------------------------------------------

    ---------------------------------------------------------
    | B | C | A | B | C | A | B | C | A | B | C | A | B | C 
... --------------------------------------------------------- ...
    | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 
    ---------------------------------------------------------

                                        -------------------------
                                        | A | B | C | A | B | C |
                                    ... -------------------------
                                        | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
                                        -------------------------
```

Is this possible? Is it also possible to get control of the splitting behaviour. That is if the vertical line between columns should appear before, after, on both sides of or nowhere at the split. Thanks!

Comment: You should type several tables by hand, as I see it.

Comment: @Bernard, that was a very unsatisfying answer ':D Surely there must be a way of accomplishing this. What if I gather more data and my table grows? Doing this manually would be a major hassle.

Comment: [How to automatically line-break a wide table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/408393/134144) is related, but I agree with Bernard that this task should be performed manually. Probably you could also transpose the whole table?

Comment: @leandriis, As this table is only two rows transposing it wastes a lot of space unfortunately. Otherwise yes.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how to do that automagically.